# Ошибка при чтении данных из SQL

Tags: android, sql

Думаю, много слов тут не нужно.

**Код:**

```
    public Long getTaskId(String task, String table){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {task};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table, null,
            "task = ?", selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    cursor.close();
    Long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    return id;
}
```

**Лог:**

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM home WHERE task = ?
```

Comment: Вы же закрыли а потом пытаетесь прочитать закрытое)))))

Comment: `cursor.close();` ниже `Long id =...` поставьте)

Comment: Исправил, но появилась другая ошибка `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1`. В sql для сравнения используют "=" или "=="?